# Error in excel 2016 when adding a formula

Tags: excel-2016

I have an Excel formula that works fine in excel 2003 but in Excel 2016 I get the error when clicking on Data Validation.

**"You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Data Validation criteria"**

My formula is

=INDIRECT("IQ!"&LEFT($T28, 2)&"11"):INDIRECT("IQ!"&LEFT($T28, 2)&11+$V28)

I had to do the formula like this, as the business users cannot update the formula themselves.
I have a dropdown list in another sheet within Excel, which this refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious why Excel doesn't accept the current format of Indirect range..

However, one workaround could be to create a named range:

[image]

And then refer to the named range (test1) in your data validation list:

[image]

Comment: You sir, are a legend!  Worked absolutely perfectly, not sure why I didn't think of that!! Thanks very much

Comment: You too!! No problem, glad it helped :D!! take care :)!